# Raspberry Pi Acces Point - How to connect to port 80 of client

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, esp8266, access-point

I have set up my Raspberry Pi as Access Point. Working!
I have my wlan0 as access point. Working!
I have my eth0 as connection to my Homenetwork (connection to the internet). Working!

Now to my question,

I have an ESP 8266 which I have already connected successfully to my Raspberry Pi wlan0.
(Serial output of ESP 8266 shows an IP in the wlan0 range!

But I can't connect to Webserver on ESP ...
I tried an Portscan:
Portscan in Raspberry Pi Wifi -> No Port open.
Portscan in my Homenetwork (changed the credentials in ESP->main.c) -> Port is open!

I tried to Ping my ESP8266 -> Ping is working within Raspberry Pi Access Point!

So does anyone has an idea, why port 80 is blocked within raspberry pi wifi Access Point?

Thanks!

Comment: After reading your question I am not sure from where exactly you are trying to connect to ESP. Are you attempting TCP connection from within Pi to port 80 of ESP IP?

Comment: Yes, I want to connect from the Raspberry Pi directly to the ESP IP to port 80.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to something else than ESP and connected to WiFi? Have you tried logging IP traffic from inside Pi (tcpdump/iptables rules to log packets/...) to confirm stage/place where the packet is dropped/lost?

Comment: I found the error! 
While connecting from the ESP to the wifi Network i had to set my WiFi mode:                     —> WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); // was missing
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password)

Answer (score 0):

I found the error! While connecting from the ESP to the wifi Network i had to set my

```
WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); // this line was missing in main.c of Esp
WiFi.begin(ssid, password)
```

Thanks.